# N64 Zelda Rumble on Wii?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii, hardware, nintendo-64, zelda-ocarina-of-time

For Zelda Ocarina of Time and Majora's Mask, I'm considering getting a Wii instead of N64, so that the graphics will be better. I'm not currently interested in Wii U or 3DS. Leary of GameCube.

However, before buying the setup; I'm concerned about whether Rumble feature will be present. I read that the Wii's Classic Controller has no rumble pack.

The GameCube controller does have rumble, but is it compatible with OOT on the Wii? I also read some reference to which 'version' of OOT you get. (e.g. Virtual Console or some master/collector's edition; maybe a GC disc - not sure)

Alternatively, maybe there's a way to get the original N64 controller on Wii?

How can I be sure that rumble will work with the Wii,
or am I better off getting the original N64? (with inferior graphics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer with certainty that Virtual Console games are the vast majority of the time unmodified ROMs taken from the original console. In this case it would be the Nintendo 64 cartridges for Ocarina of Time and Majora's Mask, with some small changes. If you want a lot more detail on exactly what is different, [refer to this third party change log](http://zeldaspeedruns.com/oot/generalknowledge/version-differences).

As for controller Rumble support, I have to go by what searches reveal, [which aren't promising](https://www.engadget.com/2006/11/09/virtual-consoles-n64-titles-dont-rumble/). It's possible they added some support later, but I can't say for sure without digging out my Wii and GameCube controllers.

I believe there are adapters to pass the GameCube port to an N64 controller, but they are probably hard to find now. Button mapping is difficult because of how different these controllers are, and it would almost certainly not support Rumble.

---

Now I know you said that you are not interested in the 3DS, but the 3D versions of both games are hugely improved, and the best way to play them… if you can handle a portable console. I'd suggest looking up some videos comparing versions before you settle on your decision.

Comment: I can confirm that there's no rumble when playing any of the Virtual Console versions on the Wii using a GameCube controller.

Comment: Does the GameCube port support Rumble, with the GameCube Controller, on the Wii?

Comment: http://www.raphnet-tech.com/products/n64_to_wii/

Comment: @musicwithoutpaper Yes, the GameCube controller can Rumble when connected to the Wii, but only with games built to target GameCube controllers specifically. According to mmKALLL no Virtual Console games do this. The adaptor you linked to would only Rumble when a game would have Rumbled for a GameCube controller.

Comment: @musicwithoutpaper Maybe you are not interested in emulation at all, but using the Saitek P2600 controller with Project64 has been amazing.